# Registering ActiveX Server with Spaces in Path

Tags: delphi, com, activex

I have an ActiveX Com Server, written in Delphi.  It works fine.  I noticed a difference however when registering it when the file is in a directory that has spaces.  For example, after executing the command.

> **C:\Path With Spaces>** AutomationLibrary.exe /regserver

**The following keys are created.**

```
HKCR\TypeLib\{BFAC1B1F-9520-4B2E-BB92-61D0CDBD7D98}\1.0\0\win32 REG_SZ C:\Path With Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKCR\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{BFAC1B1F-9520-4B2E-BB92-61D0CDBD7D98}\1.0\0\win32 REG_SZ C:\Path With Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{BFAC1B1F-9520-4B2E-BB92-61D0CDBD7D98}\1.0\0\win32    REG_SZ C:\Path With Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{BFAC1B1F-9520-4B2E-BB92-61D0CDBD7D98}\1.0\0\win32 C:\Path With Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
```

**If however I execute the following instead.**

> **C:\Path_No_Spaces>** AutomationLibrary.exe /regserver

```
HKCR\CLSID\{626F20B7-887E-456F-91C5-1BD7E973978D}\LocalServer32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKCR\CLSID\{B25708A9-4A44-44AF-915D-7F24C8E0D5AE}\LocalServer32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKCR\TypeLib\{BFAC1B1F-9520-4B2E-BB92-61D0CDBD7D98}\1.0\0\win32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{626F20B7-887E-456F-91C5-1BD7E973978D}\LocalServer32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe 
HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{B25708A9-4A44-44AF-915D-7F24C8E0D5AE}\LocalServer32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe 
HKCR\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{BFAC1B1F-9520-4B2E-BB92-61D0CDBD7D98}\1.0\0\win32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{626F20B7-887E-456F-91C5-1BD7E973978D}\LocalServer32C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe 
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{B25708A9-4A44-44AF-915D-7F24C8E0D5AE}\LocalServer32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{BFAC1B1F-9520-4B2E-BB92-61D0CDBD7D98}\1.0\0\win32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe    
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{626F20B7-887E-456F-91C5-1BD7E973978D}\LocalServer32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{B25708A9-4A44-44AF-915D-7F24C8E0D5AE}\LocalServer32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe    
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{BFAC1B1F-9520-4B2E-BB92-61D0CDBD7D98}\1.0\0\win32 C:\Path_No_Spaces\AutomationLibrary.exe
```

Why the difference and how can I fix?  Double quotes don't seem to work.  Comments and suggestions are most welcome.  I am running this on Windows7 Enterprise SP1, 64 bit.

Comment: which version of delphi?

Comment: Your examples are both invalid. Neither of them will execute, because \regserver is interpreted as a directory. (The command-line switch character in DOS/Windows is /, not `\\`.) If you have a question, post valid information.

Comment: This seems like something you could investigate with the debugger. You should try that.

Comment: Sorry for the typo with the slash. It's fixed.

Comment: I have the source in D6 and DXE.  I didn't write the ActiveX Server, but I can compile if needed.  Also, I wasn't thinking this was a Delphi Issue, more of a general ActiveX issue.  I take it an ActiveX server written in any language should register properly with spaces in the path?  Thank you for the responses.